# How to make player shooting?

Tags: python, pygame

this my code

```
import math
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
width, height = 640, 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
acc=[0,0]
arrows = []
keys = [False, False, False, False]
playerpos = [100,100]

player = pygame.image.load("resources/images/dude.png")
grass = pygame.image.load("resources/images/grass.png")
castle = pygame.image.load("resources/images/castle.png")
arrow = pygame.image.load("resources/images/bullet.png")

while 1:
    screen.fill(0)
    for bullet in arrows:
        index = 0
        velx = math.cos(bullet[0])*10
        vely = math.sin(bullet[0])*10
        bullet[1] += velx
        bullet[2] += vely
        if bullet[1] <- 64 or bullet[1]>640 or bullet[2] <- 64 or bullet[2] > 480:
            arrows.pop(index)
        index += 1
        for projectile in arrows:
            arrow1 = pygame.transform.rotate(arrow, 360-projectile[0]*57.29)
        screen.blit(arrow1, (projectile[1], projectile[2]))
for x in range(int(width/grass.get_width()+1)):
    for y in range(int(height/grass.get_height()+1)):
        screen.blit(grass,(x*100,y*100))
screen.blit(castle,(0,30))
screen.blit(castle,(0,135))
screen.blit(castle,(0,240))
screen.blit(castle,(0,345 ))
position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
angle = math.atan2(position[1]-(playerpos[1]+32),position[0]-(playerpos[0]+26))
playerrot = pygame.transform.rotate(player, 360-angle*57.29)
playerpos1 = (playerpos[0]-playerrot.get_rect().width/2, playerpos[1]-playerrot.get_rect().height/2)
screen.blit(playerrot, playerpos1)
pygame.display.flip()

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        exit(0)
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key==K_w:
            keys[0]=True
        elif event.key==K_a:
            keys[1]=True
        elif event.key==K_s:
            keys[2]=True
        elif event.key==K_d:
            keys[3]=True
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key==pygame.K_w:
            keys[0]=False
        elif event.key==pygame.K_a:
            keys[1]=False
        elif event.key==pygame.K_s:
            keys[2]=False
        elif event.key==pygame.K_d:
            keys[3]=False

    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        acc[1] += 1
        arrows.append([math.atan2(position[1]-(playerpos1[1]+32),position[0]-(playerpos1[0]+26)),playerpos1[0]+32,playerpos1[1]+32])
    if keys[0]:
        playerpos[1]-=5
    elif keys[2]:
        playerpos[1]+=5
    if keys[1]:
        playerpos[0]-=5
    elif keys[3]:
        playerpos[0]+=5
```

please explain to me how to make player shooting. i already tried watching every tutorial and still confusing me

```
for bullet in arrows:
    index = 0
    velx = math.cos(bullet[0])*10
    vely = math.sin(bullet[0])*10
    bullet[1] += velx
    bullet[2] += vely
    if bullet[1] <- 64 or bullet[1]>640 or bullet[2] <- 64 or bullet[2] > 480:
        arrows.pop(index)
    index += 1
    for projectile in arrows:
        arrow1 = pygame.transform.rotate(arrow, 360-projectile[0]*57.29)
        screen.blit(arrow1, (projectile[1], projectile[2]))
```

i kinda confuse at this part i don't get any error and player still not shooting. please explain why it not working and explain how it works, i follow the instruction in a website .

Comment: Try walking us through what you tried based on the best tutorial that you've found so far. Explain what steps made sense, and where you ran into steps that you found confusing. That way, answers can focus on solving the confusing parts. Without this information, we might try explaining it the same way as tutorials you've found did, which wouldn't be very helpful. (After all, you've already watched ALL tutorials on the entire Internet - you've probably seen all the common ways of explaining this and for some reason none of them helped you. We need to figure out that reason to find a new way)

Comment: There's a number of things that are probably mistakes. For example, it's not clear to me why you have a doubly nested loop both parts of which iterate on `arrows`. And you're also resetting `index` every pass, which cancels out having incremented it later in the loop. But without more of an explanation of what you're trying to accomplish with the various parts of code, it's hard to know for sure.